# Asbestos in popcorn ceiling?

Tags: asbestos

Considering hanging a chandelier in my popcorn ceiling. Building was built in 1972 in Boston. Unclear if it's been renovated since but I'm assuming probably has? Is this a bad idea because the popcorn ceiling might have asbestos? Or unlikely? And even if there is asbestos are the two holes for the anchors enough to release asbestos?

Comment: This is not something you need to worry about, unless worrying about stuff is kinda your thing. It's a problem over the long-term in large amounts, not tiny incidental exposures. If it's badly crumbling and they practice gymnastics or death metal above you, it might be worth testing.

Comment: Use a mask and no worries.  Use a vacuum for the dust and even less worries.  Work with asbestos for many, many years, you should worry.  I would worry more if the two anchors are enough to keep the chandelier from falling on your head.

Comment: Installed asbestos is NOT a health risk. If you take the stuff, grind it up into a powder, and sniff it, then it becomes a problem.

Comment: I'm with @crip659 - I'm far more concerned about the "two holes for the anchors" being enough to hold up the chandelier...